# Java : Class wrapper using generic

Tags: java, generics, typechecking

I would in some way store many different type in a HashMap, but in a way that when i extract them they will be well typed (and not an object).

So i think about a wrapper that use generics

```
 public class Value <T>
 {
     private T innerValue ;

     public Value ( T _value )
     {
         innerValue = _value ;
     }

     public T read ()
     {
         return innerValue ;
     }
 }
```

but it does not work, for a test i made :

```
 Value <Integer> va = new Value <Integer> ( 1 ) ;
 Value vc = va ;
 int restA = vc.read();
```

but i get a design time error, because vc.read() will return an Object() and not an Integer.
So what should i do to avoid this behaviour? (if possible i would a solution that prevent 'va' from losing information about T instead of other workaround)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe it will be possible to do this until some future version of Java in which generics are "reified", and parameterized types in Java are no longer implemented using erasure.

Comment: @DavidConrad which I don't believe will ever happen.

Comment: very sad.
So for the same reason there is no way to deserialize an object directly to the right type, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You casted `va` to a raw `Value`, `vc`.  When you use the raw form of a class, your `T` generic type parameter is replaced by `Object`.  So you cannot assign an `Object` to an `int`.

If you just call `va.read()`, then it will return an `Integer`, which will be unboxed to an `int` upon assignment to `restA`.

Comment: so i suppose that all Value's instances, stored inside HashMap, lose their generic type in the same way. (and i can not image all possible types who someone could put inside this HashMap). Is there any way in which i may store T inside a private field of my Value's instance?

Comment: You could store a `Class<T>`, but that gets you very little over just having `Object` as the value type of a `HashMap`, because you'd still have to test the type before casting it to access the class-specific methods anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> I would in some way store many different type in a HashMap, but in a
>   way that when i extract them they will be well typed (and not an
>   object).

Short answer is: this is not possible. And type erasure is not the reason: it simply does not make much sense to have this information at compile time. Suppose that Java compiler had some kind of mechanism to keep track of the types of objects stuffed into a HashMap. Then it also would have to cope with something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Value<?>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Value<?>>;
if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    myMap.put(0, new Value<String>("hello world"));
} else {
    myMap.put(0, new Value<MacaroniExtruder>(new MacaroniExtruder()));
}
[whatDoYouWantToWriteHere?] value = myMap.get(0);
```

What you want is probably rather something like "type-union". Unfortunately, it does not exist neither in Java, nor in Scala (where we have case-classes, which are almost just as good for that). So all you can do is basically:

A) Use polymorphism, define a proper interface, so that the concrete implementations become completely irrelevant, and work with that interface as second argument to your hash Map (preferred).

B) Use instanceof and long if-else switches (ugly)